# install ArUco using openCV.

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I am trying to install ArUco using openCV.But I am facing an issue regarding incorrect Cmake command.The error is as follows:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_define_module"

My Cmakelists.txt file reads:

set(the_description "ArUco Marker Detection")
ocv_define_module(aruco opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_calib3d WRAP python java)

The command in terminal which lead to this error is as follows:

cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..

I am working on ubuntu 14.04.5 OS. I am completely new to this OS as well as to openCV and ArUco. Can anyone please tell me the steps to debug this error.

Comment: Easily googled by error message: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/569. In short: `CMakeLists.txt` you created cannot be built *standalone*, you need to build it as a part of OpenCV.

Comment: Can you please tell me the step wise commands to proceed in the right direction to debug this error.Actually I am a complete newbie to these things.

Comment: What is unclear from [README](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md) about building contrib modules?

Comment: Thanks for the help its done. There was a silly directory path issue. But thanks for your help.